# from Windows 802.1X connection instructions to linux

Tags: debian, wpa-supplicant, radius, 802.1x

Was looking for PEAP tutorials for raspbian but didn't found any solution so far.

In our manual for the LAN-connection to our network are following steps:

1. Activate IEEE 802.1X-authentification
2. Set Userauthentification as authentification-mode
3. Uncheck the option to check the identity of the server through Certificate
4. Select EAP-MSCHAP-V2 as authentification-method
5. Proceed and enter credentials:
   domainxxx\usernamexxx
   passwordxxx

How can I reproduce these steps for raspbian?

Edit (efforts so far):

etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
       key_mgmt=IEEE8021X
       eap=PEAP
       identity="domainxxx\usernamexxx"
       password="passwordxxx"
       phase1="peaplabel=0"
       phase2="auth=MSCHAPV2"
}
```

edited the line "iface eth0 inet manual" from /etc/network/interfaces to:

```
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Currently following error:

```
    `eth0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-STARTED EAP authentication started
eth0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PROPOSED-METHOD vendor=0 method=25
eth0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-METHOD EAP vendor 0 method 25 (PEAP) selected
eth0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PEER-CERT depth=0 subject='/DC=de/DC=MyDcxxxx/DC=domainxxx/CN=CNxxx'
eth0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PEER-CERT depth=0 subject='/DC=de/DC=MyDcxxxx/DC=domainxxx/CN=CNxxx'
eth0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PEER-CERT depth=0 subject='/DC=de/DC=MyDcxxxx/DC=domainxxx/CN=CNxxx'
SSL: SSL3 alert: write (local SSL3 detected an error):fatal:decrypt error
OpenSSL: openssl_handshake - SSL_connect error:04091068:rsa routines:INT_RSA_VERIFY:bad signature
OpenSSL: pending error: error:1408D07B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_KEY_EXCHANGE:bad signature
eth0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-FAILURE EAP authentication failed`
```

Distro is Raspbian.
OpenSSL version is 1.0.1t 3 May 2016

Comment: Please document what have you tried so far with `wpa-supplicant`; this group is more geared to helping people with specific doubts than writing full tutorials.

Comment: I'm sorry, I assumed my efforts  were meaningless due to just incomprehension. I edited my question.

Comment: The ssl error could either be an old wpa_supplicant version, or a weak protocolo in the actual certificate....oddly enough wap_supplicant is supposed to ignore the certificate if you do not configure the certificate bits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are using MSCHAPv2 auth, you need the hash of the password, and not the actual password.

So, a password in cleartext as you have it now

```
password="passwordxx"
```

won't work.

Try

```
$echo -n passwordxx | iconv -t utf16le | openssl md4
cb21bd8890caee216f87cfb8d3248fe9
```

And then replace in `etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` the `password` line with the hash obtained running the last command.

Example derivated from `passwordxx`:

```
password=hash:cb21bd8890caee216f87cfb8d3248fe9
```

Depending on the central RADIUS server configuration, you might also need to add  an `anonymous_identity`, I would also add it for starters identical to the directive `identity`.

```
anonymous_identity="domainxxx\usernamexxx""
```

I also think key_mgmt is  key_mgmt=WPA-EAP (a bit unsure about this point, test it out)

As in:

```
network={
   key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
   eap=PEAP
   identity="domainxxx\usernamexxx"
   anonymous_identity="domainxxx\usernamexxx"
   password=hash:cb21bd8890caee216f87cfb8d3248fe9
   phase1="peaplabel=0"
   phase2="auth=MSCHAPV2"
}
```

If all else fails, and it does not authenticate, I do recommend talking with your local network administrator to check up the local details.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation. But it's not a Wi-fi connection. I followed your steps and the error SSL: SSL3 alert: ddecrypt error appears.

Comment: My fault, it if not an wifi connection, you do not need SSID. In which step do you have SSL3 alerts? Any errors in `var/log/wpa_supplicant.log`?

Comment: Please also add to your question dristo name and version, and the output of `openssl version`.

Comment: Edited the question with the whole error.